# C++: circular dependency issue

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

I'm having a problem with circular dependencies, I suppose this is a design flaw from introducing the Game class in the wrong way.

Game.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

#include "GameScreen.h"
#include "TitleScreen.h"

class Game
{
protected:
    sf::RenderWindow window;

    GameScreen* CurrentGameScreen;
    TitleScreen Title;

public:
    Game(void);
    ~Game(void);

    sf::RenderWindow getWindow(void);

    void Run();
    void Close();
};
```

GameScreen.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "Game.h"

class GameScreen
{
public:
    GameScreen(void);
    ~GameScreen(void);

    virtual void LoadAllResources() {};
    virtual void DrawScreen(Game* game) {};
    virtual void Update(Game* game) {};
};
```

TitleScreen.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

#include "GameScreen.h"

class TitleScreen : public virtual GameScreen
{
private:
    sf::Texture title_screen;
    sf::Sprite titleScreen;

    sf::Font font;
    sf::Text menuExit;

public:
    TitleScreen(void);
    ~TitleScreen(void);

    void LoadAllResources();
    void DrawScreen(Game* game);
    void Update(Game* game);
};
```

Then there's the main file:

```
#include "Game.h"

int main()
{
    Game game;
    game.Run();

    //sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Test");

    //GameScreen* currentScreen;
    //TitleScreen titleScreen;

    //currentScreen = &titleScreen;

    //while (window.isOpen())
    //{
    //  currentScreen->Update(&window);
    //  currentScreen->DrawScreen(&window);
    //}

    return 0;
}
```

*GameScreen.h* and *TitleScreen.h* raise a handful of **C2061**. From what I understand these are caused by circular dependencies between Game.h and Gamescreen.h.

*TitleScreen.h* is giving me **error C2504: 'GameScreen' : base class undefined**.

*Game.h*: on lines 12 and 13, give **C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'**, although I'm not sure where this is coming from and my IDE is not giving me any syntax errors.

If I remove the `#include` statement from GameScreen.h and substitute it with a forward declaration `class Game;` (which I guess breaks the circular dependency?) most of the above is solved, but *TitleScreen.cpp* throws a set of **C2027**, **C2227** and **C2228** (**undefined type**, **left of ->** and **left of .**) every time I try to access a Game object. IntelliSense points out that a *pointer to an incomplete class is not allowed*.

I got it working before introducing the Game class - `DrawScreen()` and `Update()` would take as argument a pointer to window (`sf::RenderWindow* window`). There's part of the old code left in main.cpp.

Comment: As answered @piokuc, you need a [Forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration)

Answer (score 4):

In the `GameScreen.h` you should declare the `Game` class instead of including its whole header file, so this:

```
class Game;
```

instead of:

```
#include "Game.h"
```